# How can I get correct coordinates from a diamond isometric map created in Tiled?

Tags: monogame, isometric, coordinates, tiled, monogame-extended

I am rendering a diamond isometric map created in Tiled using `Monogame.Extended.Tiled` package.

Here is where I'm trying to spawn a player with an object at coordinates `224,224` on my map

[image: Spawn]

Here is where it actually spawns within the game world.
[image: Actual game]

I have some debug info at the top of the screenshot. `0, 0` in the gameworld is where the first tile is in the middle of the screen.

I understand how to get the correct coordinates when it is a staggered map. I know for a diamond it involves something with the halving the screen size and height but I'm personally stuck and have tried searching for this answer somewhere.

I just want to be able to convert the coordinates Tiled puts out, into the world space. If it comes to it, I will just use my own map renderer and go back to staggered but I would prefer not to.

My tiles are 64px wide, 32px tall

As usual, any help is appreciated and will provide any extra information.

---

## Edit

Here are updated screenshots with regards to the comment. I hope they're correct.

Below are tiles with the coordinates + origin. These are objects in Tiled where I wish to place something.

[image]

Here is where they are actually rendered.

[image]

I am confused as to why the origin is offset on the Y coordinate like that but this is rendered using `Monogame.Extended`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want something like...

```
pixelY = tileHeight * (tileX + tileY)/2 + tileHeight;
pixelX = tileWidth  * (tileX - tileY)/2;
```

Comment: Looks like that might solve it. I will give it try when I get a chance soon. I was getting very confused because MonoGame.Extended has a `worldToScreen` method but it wasn't lining anything up correct. Thanks in advance and I will accept this once I check it works.

Comment: I've never used MonoGame.Extended, but I wonder whether the "world" it refers to there is something like a physics world, rather than the tilemap.

Comment: Yeah it just needed this equation ontop of that `worldToScreen` method. Thanks for saving me from this headache.

Comment: Want to post your own answer showing how to incorporate this into your code alongside `worldToScreen`? Maybe call it a function `tileToWorld`  That way you can accept your own answer and keep your bounty — I really don't need it.

Comment: Yeah I probably will make it an answer cheers. Just curious though, I'm doing some debugging and I'm wondering does any of the `32` represent the pixel width or height? My tiles are 64*32 so I was wondering if it's supposed to represent any of them

Comment: I've edited the answer to describe where the 32 is coming from, rather than leaving it as a magic number.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that was the case but wanted to double check. Myy tile coordinate calculator was a bit off because `Vector2` in Monogame uses `float` for it's values, which in turn was causing an issue for calculations. Converting those to ints has fixed that.

The border tile gets placed at the origin correctly still (which wasn't happening at all prior to your answer), just the other tiles are a bit off so I'm doing a bit more debugging with that but the answer you provided definitely gave me some baseline to get this sorted. I will provide an answer once I get time later to solve this.